# How to set cypress assertion on javascript object fetch through ag-grid

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cypress, assertion

As I am new to this UI automation/cypress world, need help to setting up the assertion on javascript object return by **cypress-ag-grid** package

My code is reading ag-grid data

```
cy.get("#myGrid").getAgGridData().should((data)=>{
cy.log(data)
})
```

Which is printing below object in console

```
[
{ id: 1, name: "tata", saftyRating: "50" },
{ id: 2, name: "maruti", saftyRating: "50" },
{ id: 3, name: "ford", saftyRating: "45" }
]
```

**What all I want to iterate the safety rating value and put cypress assertion that value is greater than 50**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `cy.should()`, you can simply iterate through the yielded `data` variable using [JavaScript's `array.forEach()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
cy.get("#myGrid").getAgGridData().should((data)=>{
  data.forEach(({ saftyRating }) => {
    // using chai
    expect(+saftyRating).to.be.greaterThan(50);
    // using cypress
    cy.wrap(+saftyRating).should('be.gt', 50);
  })
});
```

Comment: I think we first need to covert the saftyRating value to number then only this assertion will work

Comment: Ah good call out - missed that it was a string instead of a number. Updated!

Comment: can you please help me with this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75830614/how-to-chain-two-assertion-statment-in-or-form-in-cypress