# How to chain two assertion statment in OR condition in cypress

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cypress, assertion

As I am new to this UI automation/cypress world, need help to setting up the assertion on javascript object return by **cypress-ag-grid** package

My code is reading ag-grid data

```
cy.get("#myGrid").getAgGridData().should((data)=>{
cy.log(data)
})
```

Which is printing below object in console

```
[
{ id: 1, name: "tata", saftyRating: "-50" },
{ id: 2, name: "maruti", saftyRating: "-50" },
{ id: 3, name: "ford", saftyRating: "" },
{ id: 4, name: "skoda", saftyRating: "" }
]
```

When I iterate over the saftyRating field

```
cy.get("#myGrid").getAgGridData().should((data)=>{
  data.forEach(({ saftyRating }) => {
    cy.wrap(+saftyRating).should('be.lt', -50);
  })
});
```

It is failing because **blank** value it is converting **0** and 0 is not less than equal to -50

All I want is to append one more assert condition in **OR** form
Which should be like this `.should('be.eq', 0);`
So that that the test case passes

All any better approach to handle this is also welcome

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, using `+saftyRating` is the wrong approach in this case, because the grid may contain a genuine `0` rating.

An empty value such as `saftyRating: ""` is different to a zero value such as `saftyRating: "0"` - one is explicitly entered, the other is effectively "don't know".

To check two (or more) conditions, use a callback function something like

```js
data.forEach(({ saftyRating }) => {
  cy.wrap(saftyRating)
    .should(value => {
      expect(value === '' || +value <= -50).to eq(true)
    })
})
```

or with `satisfy`

```js
data.forEach(({ saftyRating }) => {
  cy.wrap(saftyRating)
    .should('satisfy', (value) => {
      return value === '' || +value <= -50
    })
})
```

You can easily extend the conditions if other requirements arise.

More examples at this answer [How to check that element has either of classes in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62023455/16997707)

Answer (score 2):

None of your safety ratings are less than -50, so `.should('be.lt', -50)` fails every data item.

Change it to `.should('be.lte', -50)` which means "less than or equal".